# $_GET in AJAX variable modal bootstrap

Tags: php, ajax

I got load content via eModal and i got url with id`s example: #index.php?id=1&idt=2 
How can in ajax load content of modal use this parameters id and idt ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {/* activate scroll spy menu */

    var iconPrefix = '.fa-';


    $(iconPrefix + 'mixcloud').click(ajaxDemo);
    ///////////////////* Implementation *///////////////////

    // Demos
    function ajaxDemo() {
        var title = 'Znaczniki H1';
        var params = {
            buttons: [
               { text: 'Close', close: true, style: 'danger' },
               { text: 'New content', close: false, style: 'success', click: ajaxDemo }
            ],
            size: eModal.size.lg,
            title: title,
            url: 'views/h1.php'
        };

        return eModal
            .ajax(params)
            .then(function () { alert('Ajax Request complete!!!!', title) });
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: inside h1.php is function wich need to use this parameters to show up some charts.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you want to obtain the GET Param `id` of the actual page you're in.

```
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/index.html?id=joe";
var url = new URL(url_string);
var id = url.searchParams.get("id");
```

I  took this function from this post: [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters#)

Comment: I wanna load content from h1.php but inside this h1.php is function wich need atribute from url

Comment: example: i am on webside #index.php?id=1&idt=2 and there is modal where ajax load inside h1.php and there is function wich need id from url

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to better fit your question I hope.

Comment: i dont know why not get id or idt to url 
    var iconPrefix = '.fa-';
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var idt = $(this).attr('idt');

    $(iconPrefix + 'mixcloud').click(ajaxDemo);
    function ajaxDemo() {
        var title = 'Znaczniki H1';

        var params = {
            ],
            size: eModal.size.lg,
            title: title,
            url: 'views/h1.php?id='+id+'&idt='+idt,
                  };

        return eModal
            .ajax(params)
            .then(function () { alert('Ajax Request complete!!!!', title) });

Comment: I just want to clarify something. The `id` and `idt` values are attributes of the Dom element(the icon) or GET Param of the actual page Uri?

Comment: GET Param of the actual page Uri